# How to Use Select Case in MySql

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    PROCEDURE `cheque_alert`.`SavePoData`(IN poNo VARCHAR(25),IN releaseOrderDate DATE,IN expiryDate DATE,IN enteredDateTime DATETIME,IN enteredBy VARCHAR(8) ,
    IN poItemCode VARCHAR(25),IN poItemsId CHAR(1),IN poItemDescription VARCHAR(75),IN quantity DOUBLE,IN amount DOUBLE
    )

    BEGIN
        SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT 1 FROM `cheque_alert`.`po_main` WHERE po_no=poNo)>0)
        THEN        
        INSERT INTO `cheque_alert`.`po_items_details`
            (`pomainid_id`,
             `po_item_code`,
             `po_items_id`,
             `po_item_description`,
             `quantity`,
             `amount`)
        VALUES ((SELECT id FROM `cheque_alert`.`po_main` WHERE po_no =poNo),
            poItemCode,poItemsId,poItemDescription,quantity,amount) 

    ELSE        
        INSERT INTO `cheque_alert`.`po_main`
            (`po_no`,
             `release_order_date`,
             `expiry_date`,
             `entered_date_time`,
             `entered_by`)
        VALUES (poNo,releaseOrderDate,expiryDate,enteredDateTime,(SELECT ID FROM cheque_alert.user_login WHERE USER_ID=enteredBy));

        INSERT INTO `cheque_alert`.`po_items_details`
            (`pomainid_id`,
             `po_item_code`,
             `po_items_id`,
             `po_item_description`,
             `quantity`,
             `amount`)
        VALUES ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(),
            poItemCode,
            poItemsId,
            poItemDescription,
            quantity,
            amount);

    END;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

produces error:

> Error Code : 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO `cheque_alert`.`po_items_details`
>               (`pomainid_id`,
>                `po_item_cod' at line 14

please let me know the mistake i have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IF-ELSE structure should be like this:

```
IF(some query to check something) THEN
BEGIN
    insert something
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    insert something
    insert something else
END
```

Meanwhile CASE will only work on defining some value, not the whole query. For example:

```
SELECT CASE name WHEN 'hamburger' THEN 'unhealthy' ELSE 'healthy' END
FROM food
```

Comment: Error Code : 1064
You have an error near 'ELSE        
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO `cheque_alert`.`po_main`
       (po_no,relea' at line 24